# Implementing ssl using pem format gives me an error

Tags: node.js, ssl

I am trying to install a project someone else has written. He did not provide any instructions on how to install the project. I have never used node js before so any help will be greatly appreciated.

AFAIK the server module expects a pem format certificate which I have generated using the following tutorial
https://supportportal.juniper.net/s/article/Generate-a-self-signed-SSL-certificate-in-PEM-format-using-OpenSSL?language=en_US

I pointed the configuration file to the pem files but I get an error when I try starting the project.

```
Error: error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt
    at Object.createSecureContext (_tls_common.js:158:17)
    at Server.setSecureContext (_tls_wrap.js:1080:27)
    at Server (_tls_wrap.js:960:8)
    at new Server (https.js:61:14)
    at Object.createServer (https.js:84:10)
    at module.exports (/home/alfred/AccentaG4/src/mpu/server/server.js:27:26)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/alfred/AccentaG4/src/mpu/server/alarm.js:13:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:816:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:827:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:685:32)
```

server.js

```
const fs = require('fs')
const https = require('https')
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const WebSocket = require('ws')
const {Subject, merge} = require('rxjs')
const {filter, throttleTime} = require('rxjs/operators')
const {ENABLE_CHAR} = require('./constants')
const log = require('./log')

module.exports = ({port, ssl}) => {
    const app = express()

    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client')))
    
    app.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.render('index.html')
    })

    const send$ = new Subject()
    
    const sslCredentials = {
        key: fs.readFileSync(ssl.key || __dirname + '/key.pem'),
        cert: fs.readFileSync(ssl.cert || __dirname + '/cert.pem')
    }
    
    const server = https.createServer(sslCredentials, app)
    
    const wss = new WebSocket.Server({server})
    
    server.listen(port, () => {
        log.info(`Server started on port ${port}`)
    })

    const listen = callback =>
        wss.on('connection', ws =>
            ws.on('message', message =>
                callback(message.toString('utf-8'))
            )
        )

    // const data$ = merge(
    //     send$.pipe(
    //         filter(data => data !== ENABLE_CHAR)
    //     ),
    //     send$.pipe(
    //         filter(data => data === ENABLE_CHAR),
    //         throttleTime(3000)
    //     )
    // )
    
    send$.subscribe(
        data => {
            // data !== ENABLE_CHAR && log.log('Downstream message:', {data})
            wss.clients.forEach(function (client) {
                if (client.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
                    client.send(data)
                }
            })
        }
    )
    
    const send = data =>
        send$.next(data)

    return {listen, send}
}
```

Alarm.js

```
const config = require('./config')
const Serial = require('./serial')
const Server = require('./server')
const status = require('./status')
const Notify = require('./notify')
const log = require('./log')

const serial = Serial({
    port: config.serial,
    baudRate: 115200
})

const server = Server({
    port: config.port,
    ssl: config.ssl
})

const notify = Notify(config.notify)

notify('Alarm controller started')

status
    .on('link', state =>
        notify(`Alarm panel link ${state ? 'up' : 'down'}`)
    )
    .on('armed', state =>
        notify(`Alarm ${state ? 'armed' : 'disarmed'}`)
    )
    .on('abort', state =>
        notify(`Alarm ${state ? 'aborted' : 'reset'}`)
    )
    .on('intruder', state =>
        notify(state ? 'INTRUDER [!]' : 'Intruder alarm deactivated')
    )
    .on('panic', state =>
        notify(state ? 'PANIC [!]' : 'Panic alarm deactivated')
    )
    .on('autoArm', hour =>
        log.info(`Auto-arm ${hour === -1 ? 'disabled' : `enabled at ${hour}:00`}`)
    )
    .on('autoDisarm', hour =>
        log.info(`Auto-disarm ${hour === -1 ? 'disabled' : `enabled at ${hour}:00`}`)
    )
    .on('autoDays', days =>
        log.info(`Auto-arm/disarm days: ${status.getAutoDays()}`)
    )

status.setAutoArm(config.autoArmHour)
status.setAutoDisarm(config.autoDisarmHour)

serial.listen(message => {
    switch (message.substr(0, 4)) {
    case 'HBT:':
        var staleness = parseInt(message.substring(4), 10)
        // status.update('link', staleness < 120)
        status.setLink(staleness < 120)
        break
    case 'SIG:':
        var signals = message.substring(4)
        status.setArmed(signals.charAt(0) === 'S')
        status.setAbort(signals.charAt(1) === 'A')
        status.setIntruder(signals.charAt(2) === 'I')
        status.setPanic(signals.charAt(3) === 'P')
        break
    case 'AIR:':
        var airQuality = message.substring(4)
        status.setAirQuality(airQuality)
        break
    default:
    }
    server.send(message)
})

server.listen(message => {
    if (message.substring(0, 5) === '#ARM=') {
        status.setAutoArm(parseInt(message.split('=')[1]))
        server.send('ARM:' + status.getAutoArm())
    } else if (message.substring(0, 5) === '#DIS=') {
        status.setAutoDisarm(parseInt(message.split('=')[1]))
        server.send('DIS:' + status.getAutoDisarm())
    } else if (message.substring(0, 5) === '#DAY=') {
        status.toggleAutoDay(parseInt(message.split('=')[1]))
        server.send('DAY:' + status.getAutoDays())
    } else {
        if (message === '?') {
            server.send('ARM:' + status.getAutoArm())
            server.send('DIS:' + status.getAutoDisarm())
            server.send('DAY:' + status.getAutoDays())
        }
        serial.send(message)
    }
})

setInterval(function() {
    var date = new Date()
    if (status.getArmed()) {
        if (config.autoDisarmCode
            && status.isAutoDay(date.getDay())
            && date.getHours() === status.getAutoDisarm()
            && date.getMinutes() === 0) {
            log.info('alarm auto-disarmed')
            serial.send(config.autoDisarmCode)
        }
    } else {
        if (config.autoArmCode
            && status.isAutoDay(date.getDay())
            && date.getHours() === status.getAutoArm()
            && date.getMinutes() === 0) {
            log.info('alarm auto-armed')
            serial.send(config.autoArmCode)
        }
    }
}, 60000)
```

Comment: Duplicate. But in short: you created a private key encrypted with a passphrase but did not provide the passphrase in the sslCredentials.